# Core data - context is null

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I'd like to use CoreData. I've created this coreData file manualy after some time. I'm trying to write some values to the file but the context is all the time null.

```
- (NSManagedObjectContext *)managedObjectContext {

    NSManagedObjectContext *context = nil;
    AppDelegate *delegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];


        context = [delegate managedObjectContext];
    if(context == nil)
    {
        NSLog(@"CONTEXT IS NIL");
    }

    return context;
}
```

Method has no errors but crashes here:

```
//here is null
NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];

    // Create a new managed object
    NSManagedObject *newDevice = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Kwejki" inManagedObjectContext:context];
```

The context is null. I've no idea why it is null if I'm getting this context from AppDelegate object. I'm using TabBarController in my app and it starts in the first tab. What is wrong?

UPDATE::

```
@synthesize managedObjectContext = _managedObjectContext;
@synthesize managedObjectModel = _managedObjectModel;
@synthesize persistentStoreCoordinator = _persistentStoreCoordinator;

- (NSManagedObjectContext *)managedObjectContext {

    if (self.managedObjectContext != nil) {
        return self.managedObjectContext;
        NSLog(@"managedOC - != nil");
    }

    NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *coordinator = [self persistentStoreCoordinator];
    if (coordinator != nil) {
        NSLog(@"coordinator - != nil");
//Here I get two errors below "Receiver type NSManagedObjectContext for instance message is a forward declaration"

        self.managedObjectContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init];
        [self.managedObjectContext setPersistentStoreCoordinator:coordinator];
    }
    return self.managedObjectContext;
}
```

Comment: Please post the code from AppDelegate managedObjectContext method.

Comment: ... and if you were my employee, explain why you apparently think it's appropriate to use the application delegate as a catch-all singleton. I suspect this is not a helpful comment.

Comment: I've updated post. I'm still learning objective - C @Tommy and I'm using CoreData for the first time.

Comment: I could be wrong but the message 'Receiver type NSManagedObjectContext for instance message is a forward declaration" suggests to me that you've forgotten to import the Core Data headers.

Comment: Yes I've imported that library and the error disappeared

Comment: You shouldn't be meddling with CoreData considering you're new to iOS development.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using your instance variables for lazy instantiation. Just copy the app delegate code from the Xcode template (whenever you check "Use Core Data"). Why did you change it in the first place??

```
- (NSManagedObjectContext *)managedObjectContext {
    if (_managedObjectContext != nil) {
        return _managedObjectContext;
    }

    NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *coordinator = [self persistentStoreCoordinator];
    if (coordinator != nil) {
        _managedObjectContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init];
        [_managedObjectContext setPersistentStoreCoordinator:coordinator];
    }
    return _managedObjectContext;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and it looked like I am having some issue with getting NSManagedObjectContext

```
 lazy var coreDataContext : NSManagedObjectContext = {
    (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext
}()
```

but my error was I had different entity name in ***xcdatamodeld*** file and in code i was using different while accessing it. So make sure we have same entities name as well otherwise it will throw some error.

[image]

**and** while accessing it i was having a small difference

[image]